# Min / max from nested list

Tags: python, list

```
list_a = [[0, 3], [2, 4], [25, 17]]
```

I want to iterate over `list_a` and find out the `min` and the `max` of all elements on index `[1]` for every single element of `list_a`.

My first shot was

```
min_list = min(list_a[0:][1])
max_list = max(list_a[0:][1])
```

but that was wrong. What is the correct way?

Comment: `max(second for _, second in list_a)`

Comment: `min(x[1] for x in list_a)`

Comment: *or* `max(map(lambda x:x[1], list_a))`

Comment: OR `_, max_list = max(list_a, key=lambda x:x[1])`

Comment: Thank you all for your solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehension:

```python
min_list = min([e[1] for e in list_a])
max_list = max([e[1] for e in list_a])
```

You can actually generalize this for any `i-th` element you like:

```python
i = 1
min_list = min([e[i] for e in list_a])
```

Comment: Why use a list comprehension rather than just a generator expression? The square brackets are superfluous.

Comment: Generator expressions as a parameter here might sound ambiguous for beginners, as for what the ```min``` function is taking as a parameter. (at least that was the case for me on my early days with python) so that's why I kept it like that.

Comment: In this particular case the list comprehension seems to have a very slight speed advantage over the generator expression (according to `timeit`), but for larger lists it will probably flip. The generator expression is slightly easier to read, but this answer definitely works.

Comment: You're absolutely right. It is probably also more memory friendly, as the brackets will actually generate a list object. The only reason I used the brackts is as I said, clarity.
Thank you for pointing out these points @JohnColeman